# Comparing approximate values in c# 4.0?

Tags: c#

First of all, please excuse any typo, English is not my native language.

Here's my question. I'm creating a class that represents approximate values as such:

```
public sealed class ApproximateValue
{
    public double MaxValue { get; private set; }
    public double MinValue { get; private set; }
    public double Uncertainty { get; private set; }
    public double Value { get; private set; }

    public ApproximateValue(double value, double uncertainty)
    {
        if (uncertainty < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("uncertainty", "Value must be postivie or equal to 0."); }

        this.Value = value;
        this.Uncertainty = uncertainty;
        this.MaxValue = this.Value + this.Uncertainty;
        this.MinValue = this.Value - this.Uncertainty;
    }
}
```

I want to use this class for uncertain measurments, like x = 8.31246 +/-0.0045 for example and perform calculations on these values.

I want to overload operators in this class. I don't know how to implement the >, >=, <= and < operators... The first thing I thought of is something like this:

```
    public static bool? operator >(ApproximateValue a, ApproximateValue b)
    {
        if (a == null || b == null) { return null; }

        if (a.MinValue > b.MaxValue) { return true; }
        else if (a.MaxValue < b.MinValue) { return false; }
        else { return null; }
    }
```

However, in the last case, I'm not satisfied with this 'null' as the accurate result is not 'null'. It may be 'true' or it may be 'false'.

Is there any object in .Net 4 that would help implementing this feature I am not aware of, or am I doing the correct way? I was also thinking about using an object instead of a boolean that would define in what circumstances the value is superior or not to another one rather than implementing comparison operators but I feel it's a bit too complex for what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: You can't implement comparison because you don't have a specification of how comparison should work. Write down the rules that would govern such a comparison. If you are having difficulty coming up with such rules, it's a hint that the comparison is meaningless without more context.

Comment: @Guillaume: Just as an FYI, in .NET null > null is false, null < null is false.  You shouldn't redefine what < and > means with nulls.

Comment: Why are you trying to return null on a boolean operation?  I am not sre the reason you would even allow ApproximateValue to be a nullable type.

Comment: @Jon, you're right. I think using rules will be the most accurate way to proceed. In some cases if I have - for example - 3.5 < a < 4.3 and 3.7 < b < 4.1, I may need in some cases a > b to return true because in some cases it's true and it's enough and in some cases false because it's not _always_ true.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, good tip, I didn't know about this actually.

Comment: @Ramhound, I implemented the bool? because a null was the best thing that I could see to implement an undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases where it may make more sense to define a value type (struct), which then eliminates the null case concern.  You can also modify MinValue and MaxValue to be computed properties (just implement a get method that computes the result) rather than storing them upon construction.

On a side note, comparison of approximate values is itself an approximate operation, so you need to consider the use cases for your data type; are you only intending to use comparison to determine when the ranges are non-overlapping?  It really depends on the meaning of your type.  Is this intended to represent a data point from a normally distributed data set, where the uncertainty is some number of standard deviations for the sampling?  If so, it might make more sense for a comparison operation to return a numeric probability (which couldn't be called through the comparison operator, of course.)

Comment: Good answer, I think this is the one having the best coverage of the issue and largest scope of points to consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like this.  I'd implement `IComparable<ApproximateValue>` and then define <, >, <=, and >= according to the result of `CompareTo()`:

```
public int CompareTo(ApproximateValue other)
{
    // if other is null, we are greater by default in .NET, so return 1.
    if (other == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // this is > other
    if (MinValue > other.MaxValue)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // this is < other
    if (MaxValue < other.MinValue)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // "same"-ish
    return 0;
}

public static bool operator <(ApproximateValue left, ApproximateValue right)
{
    return (left == null) ? (right != null) : left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
}

public static bool operator >(ApproximateValue left, ApproximateValue right)
{
    return (right == null) ? (left != null) : right.CompareTo(left) < 0;
}

public static bool operator <=(ApproximateValue left, ApproximateValue right)
{
    return (left == null) || left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
}

public static bool operator >=(ApproximateValue left, ApproximateValue right)
{
    return (right == null) || right.CompareTo(left) <= 0;
}

public static bool operator ==(ApproximateValue left, ApproximateValue right)
{
    return (left == null) ? (right == null) : left.CompareTo(right) == 0;
}

public static bool operator !=(ApproximateValue left, ApproximateValue right)
{
    return (left == null) ? (right != null) : left.CompareTo(left) != 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but considering the two values to be the same in the general case might not be accurate enough neither.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you need to check if `a.MaxValue == b.MinValue` also, in your current implementation that would return `null`, which seems incorrect, it should either return `true` or `false` based on how you want the spec to actually work.  I'm not sure of any built in .net functionality for this, so I believe you are going about it the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

```
return a.Value - a.Uncertainty > b.Value + b.Uncertainty
```

I wouldn't really mess with the *semantics* of `>`: I think `bool?` is a dangerous return type here. That said, given the uncertainty, you could return `true`, if `a` is *more likely* to be `> b`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to implement some form of [Ternary Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) because you want the result of applying the operators to be either True, False or Indeterminate. The problem with doing that is that you really cannot combine the built-in boolean values with your indeterminate value. So whilst you could do some limited form of comparison of two `ApproximateValues` I think that it's inappropriate to use `bool` as the result of these comparisons because that implies that the result of the comparisons can be freely combined with other expressions that result in bool values, but the possibility of an indeterminate value undermines that. For example, it makes no sense to do the following when the result of operation on the left of the OR is indeterminate.

```
ApproximateValue approx1 = ...;
ApproximateValue approx2 = ...;
bool result = ...;

bool result = approx1 > approx2 || someBool;
```

So, in my opinion, I don't think that it's a good idea to implement the comparisons as operators at all **if** you want to retain the indeterminacy. The solutions offered here eliminate the indeterminacy, which is fine, but not what was originally specified.